# how to convert a String to a Date without changing the Format

Tags: swift

I'm using Xcode 11.4.1 
In my Project I got a String with some data which I need to split up and save the Information in some variables.
now I face a problem if I try this

```
        let dateString = "12-04-2020"
        let dateFormatIn = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatIn.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        let saveDate: Date = dateFormatIn.date(from: dateString)!

        print("The date is: \(saveDate)")
```

the result which I expected is "The date is: 12-04-2019" but what I got is "The date is: 2020-04-11 15:00:00 +0000" 
what do I miss, what is this printed Date? it's not the current date ans also not the String!
I need the Date in the same format as I got it in the String.

Comment: if you want do convert a date to a string, you have to use a formatter. Just reverse the process you have done when parsing the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A `Date` is a point in time, it doesn't have a format nor a time zone.
- `print` shows the *description* – a string representation – of the date in the UTC time zone.
- Your time zone is obviously UTC +0900, `2020-04-12 00:00:00 +0900` and `2020-04-11 15:00:00 +0000` is the same point in time.
- If you want to create the date string independent of the time zone add the line

  ```
  dateFormatIn.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
  ```

Comment: thank you! I try to add this line but after that I still don't get the print out what I expect. Do I miss understand something ?!

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: ok its a date but in my app it still shoes the wrong date?! I don't get it, Sorry!

Comment: ok I played around in the Playground and I can see that the Variable has the formatted date how I expect. I still don't understand why I don't get this Value in my print out or how I can get it but this is secondary.

Comment: As I said, `print` shows a generic string representation of the date in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

```
let saveDate: Date = dateFormatIn.date(from: dateString)!
```

The ": Date" looks like a data type declaration. You're saying, "create a variable called `saveDate` of type `Date`, and initialize it from the output of `dateFormatIn.date(from: dateString)`".

So you're not printing the formatted output. You're converting the formatted output to a new `Date` object, and then printing *that*.

Try:

```
let saveDate = dateFormatIn.date(from: dateString)!
```

This should save whatever `dateFormatIn.date(from: dateString)` returns in `saveDate`.

Comment: Thank you for your feed back. This code is just a sample of the problem. In the real code I have a struct with different types of variable which I have to define and initialize. if I made the test with let saveDate = dateFormatIn.date(from: datestring)! then I got the print out but how I can declare and initialize it in a struct and in my core date?!